# Preventing layouts from expanding beyond the window size

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I'm trying to make my UI content expand nicely when the user resizes the window. I'm doing this in Qt Designer and learning about layouts and size policies.

Seems that everything is working fine for now: one layout stays within its maximum size, while another expands with the window resize, and they all stay above their minimum sizes. That's great and all, but the problem is that if I have a list with a lot of items, or if I am displaying a very large image, it will expand beyond the available window space and cause the window to be huge.

**How can I specify something along the lines of "do not expand beyond the available window space"?** I've played around with the size policies, but I couldn't get it to work. Is this something I need to set for the form itself rather than the layouts it contains?

I should specify this is the desired behavior: Display the widget as large as the available window, even if the widget content is too small. Expand/Shrink the widget to fill the window when the window is resized. Do not expand beyond the available window space. The widgets in question are 2 images (labels) and 1 list view.

Answer (score 4):

I set the size policy to "ignored" for the respective widgets. That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can set the window [maximum size](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#maximumSize-prop).